# Meaning of "provisions" in waitress job (her duties)

Tags: word-meaning

What other word can I use instead of "provisions" in the context below because i don't understand it:

One of the most common tasks is known as table sweep, and involves visiting every occupied table in an assigned section to replenish beverages, answer questions, and ensure that all is going well in terms of customer comfort. During a table sweep, customers may also have specific needs, such as a change in their order or **provisions** for additional guests.

Comment: As a reminder, you should demonstrate some initial research efforts in your question. For example, checking *[provision](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/provision_1?q=provision)* in a dictionary, which definition do you *think* might match, or are none of them satisfactory?

Comment: This seems a tad elliptical to me. The customers may need the wait-staff to make provisions for additional guests. That is, bring tables together and/or add place settings (knives, forks, spoons, plates, glasses, etc) for additional guests.

Answer (score 3):

***Provisions***, at its most basic, means *things that are provided*. All of the meanings come back to that in the end, though it's arguable as to whether it is the etymological root.

You can't make a one-for-one replacement here because the word has been used as a catch-all. Additional guests arriving at a restaurant might mean bringing out more seating, or tableware, drinks, food, colouring books, and goodness knows what else at a modern restaurant. Thus it means ***whatever may need to be provided for additional guests***.

Answer (score 0):

The use of your word

> **provisions**

in your example is fairly broad, and could mean food, drink, cutlery, place settings, the first two are covered by **order**

> a change in their order

SO, the word you may be looking for which covers nonconsumables and is just as broad and encompassing might be

> **service**
>
> ...a change in service for additional guests.